# How to get gRPC retry logs on client | java gRPC

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

I'm using gRPC for internal communication b/w 2 java services.
I configured gRPC retry using service config . I am able to get retry count in server using `"grpc-previous-rpc-attempts"` metadata header. However , I don't find any logs those are getting printed in the client app while retries are happening .

1. why gRPC is not logging retry attempts which ideally should have
   been done when retries are configured
2. Is there any way to log each
   retry attempt in the client app? This is needed for better
   observability.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this moment there is no logging support for retries, but it would be a reasonable thing to add.

You can either [file a feature request](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/new?assignees=&labels=enhancement&template=feature_report.md) to get that added, or better yet make a pull request for the change. If you decide to make the change, it should be localized to just [RetriableStream.java](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/core/src/main/java/io/grpc/internal/RetriableStream.java). Feel free to tag me (@temawi) on it and I'll review it for you.